# Android: Create SignIn app using android studio

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created a `SQLite` database and there are three columns *name* *email* and *password*. Data inserted properly, but I can not code for login so please help me for creating log in activity. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Comment: If you found this answer useful.. Please accept it by clicking the tick icon.. So that other users can also take advantage of it.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. Write code in your Database class.. Which returns the password for the username.

```
public String getSinlgeEntry(String email) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("table_name", null, " EMAIL=?", new String[]{email}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}
```

and the `login Activity`..

```
    DatabaseClassName myDb = new DatabaseClassName(this);
```

and on `login button click`

```
    String result1 = myDb.getSinlgeEntry(user_entered_email_id);
```

and compare the password entered in the `password field` and the returned password `result`

Hope this helps